# My Hibernate Criteria.list() keeps returning existing DB objects with null IDs

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Java web application that uses Hibernate to retrieve objects within the back-end.

For one particular class I keep getting the correct results in every way - except for the IDs are null.

I know that my setup is basically correct - I'm able to query for a number of other objects with everything right including the IDs - it's just with this one class I keep getting null IDs.

Here's my code.  I know there's not much to see - it's the exact same lines of code that give me results fine with all of my classes except one.  Just wondering if anyone has any ideas of why one class can give you the results with null IDs...?

```
Criteria searchCriteria = buildQBECriteria(exampleObj, orderings,                  
                          startIndex, maxQuantity, matchMode,
                          criteria, false, session);
List ret = searchCriteria.list();
```

Whenever exampleObj is anything but one particular class - the results are fine including the IDs.

Whenever exampleObj is one particular class - it returns the correct results in every way except the IDs are all null.

Thank You!
Tim

Comment: usually when I have a null id, it means I'm not dealing with a managed entity

Comment: Thanks.  I think you might well be on to something.  I'm familiar with the concept of an entity manager - but I've also checked everything I can possibly think of - including making certain it is in all the following files: applicationContext-hibernate-dao-snapshot.xml, applicationContext-hibernate-dao.xml, applicationContext-hibernate-snapshot.xml, applicationContext-hibernate.xml, applicationContext-hibernate.xml

Comment: Something else I should have mentioned - I only get the null IDs when I do a snapshot query.  The IDs come in fine when I do not do a snapshot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with snapshot queries, but can you call a flush() on the returned object? I usually only do that when persisting a new object, but it might help.  The lack of an ID makes it sound like you're dealing with a command object instead of a persisted entity.

Comment: If it's just the one class, did you remember to annotate the `id` field with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` ?

Comment: Crud.  I don't have an annotated Id field - but I don't think that's the issue.  It's really weird - but the Id field of this one object is actually not declared in the object itself - but in an object it inherits from.

Comment: And then what gets really strange is that I can do a search for another object that inherits from the same parent object - and the search results along with the IDs come back fine.

Comment: public class MajorAssemblyInventoryView extends InventoryView  //this comes back fine

Comment: public class ComponentInventoryView extends InventoryView //this comes back with nulls

Comment: Sonofagun!!!  In the hbm.xml file - this was what was doing it...

Comment: <id type="java.lang.String" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="id">

Comment: Should have been...

Comment: <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.String" unsaved-value="null">

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - if you want to offer what you did as a solution I'll give you credit.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just the one class, did you remember to annotate the id field with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

If not using annotations, maybe `<id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.String" unsaved-value="null">`